# how to support custom ATTR_?

Tags: org-mode

I maintain a backend for a custom file export format for `org-mode` and I would like to add support for custom `ATTR_LEANPUB` comments (much as LaTeX supports `ATTR_LATEX`) for tweaking visual display of images and tables and so on.

But how do I capture this information in the backend implementation? `org-export-define-derived-backend` and `org-export-define-backend` have no documentation about supporting attributes that I can see.